# Reputation paradox?

Tags: discussion

According to the page on "reputation", it states the following:

> You gain reputation when:
>
> - question is voted up: +5
> - answer is voted up: +10
> - answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
> - bounty awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)
> - site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

However, I've been voting up - and receive messages that I can't until I reach a certain threshold.

I tried posting answers - and receive messages that I can't until I reach a certain threshold.

I'm a reasonably experienced professional, so questions that I can't resolve independently are few and far between - regardless I'm anticipating I'd likewise receive a message stating I couldn't post until a reputation threshold is met.

So far I have 1 reputation point, over the past few months where I've [unsuccessfully] attempted to participate in this community.

It's a paradox - There has to be a way to gain reputation that isn't blocked by the threshold of not having enough reputation to gain reputation.

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Answer questions well, and get upvotes .. asking questions like this will likely result in the opposite (and/or a move to meta).

Comment: start with [ask] and [mcve] and you should be able to answer question but not comment(need 50 rep for that)

Comment: "I tried posting answers - and receive messages that I can't until I reach a certain threshold." That sounds odd to me. You should be able to post an answer immediately, as far as I'm aware. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @JonSkeet Might have been on a protected post.

Comment: @Kyll: That would make sense... although would that mention thresholds?

Comment: @JonSkeet It's been a while since you and I were less than 10 rep, so I can't tell. geolemon, the beginnings are always a bit tough on SO. You may want to hunt bounties to gain a lot of points quickly.

Comment: Check out [this meta question](/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow) about getting started on SO. That should help you out. As was already mentioned, you shouldn't be getting an error about rep when you try to post a question, unless it's on a protected question. If you hit it again, make sure there's not a banner under the question mentioning you need 10 rep to answer. (Posts get protected because they've received a number of off-topic, low quality answer from new users. It's a mechanism to try to help prevent these answers, but legit users can get caught.)

Comment: [Documentation on how much rep is required to unlock privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). It's a little unintuitive to find this page. You have to click on "Badges" and then the link to Privileges is on the right.

Comment: *However, I've been voting up - and receive messages that I can't until I reach a certain threshold.* You don't get rep for voting up, you get rep when someone else votes up your content. For example, someone up voted this question before it got migrated, so now you actually have 6 rep. (You unlock the ability to vote up at 15 and vote down at 125)

Comment: Thanks.  I do have a legitimate DB2 question today that is posting a challenge - I could (and will) research it independently but I'll also post it as a question to see if I can.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also - I see someone downvoted, which may indicate they didn't understand or I worded it poorly-

The problem is experiences that defy information pages on "what to do", the problem is not "where do I find info on 'what to do' ", thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have this backwards.

With the exception of accepting an answer and successfully editing posts, the way you gain reputation applies when someone *else* votes on your content.  That is, someone else has to upvote your questions and answers.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could have it backwards - please clarify?
In order for someone to vote on MY content...
...I'd first need to be able to POST content.

It seems everything I've tried to post generates a message that I don't have enough reputation to post.  That's the crux of the paradox.

Comment: @geolemon:  You *always* have enough reputation to post a question or an answer.  You may be trying to comment which indeed does require more reputation, or you may be trying to answer a protected question which requires a minimum of 10.  [Here's a chart](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) of all the privileges on the site and what reputation you have to be to unlock them.

Comment: I suppose so - Here's a good example - I don't have an answer (I'm seeking the answer), but definitely have a comment to help someone else from stepping in the same pothole.
I was forced to post it as an answer, because it said 'you need 50 reputation to comment".  The risk now is that it gets downvoted, because it's not an answer, it's a comment.  That's counterproductive, if that occurs.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510509/isdate-equivalent-of-db2/37054902#37054902

Comment: I attempted to work around this, and have been advised NOT to participate.  Not participating is not going to gain reputation.
My participation is going to be highly biased towards vetting ideas on threads congruent to solutions that I am also seeking answers on.
Very frustrating!!

Reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510509/isdate-equivalent-of-db2/37054902?noredirect=1#comment61657719_37054902

Comment: @geolemon:  Comments don't gain you reputation *anyway*.  If you have an answer then you're absolutely encouraged to contribute it.  In the example you referenced it seems like you could turn it around - explain *why* it failed and offer an alternative of your own.

Comment: Thanks. 
This is not feeling any less Twilight Zone, I'll tell you.

I did post a separate thread just now, because I'm still stuck without an alternative.
There's another thread asking the same question, that never got any answers - I hope I fare better.  I'll be duly frustrated if there's a reply that I shouldn't have posed the question because another (unanswered, aged or not) already exists. 

Thanks again.